# Error persisting records in rails after upgrading to ruby 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to upgrade my Ruby on Rails application to Ruby 3.0.1. I'm getting an error when the server is starting on Render.com. I'm also getting the same error when running specs on my local machine

#### error on render.com

```
 | F, [2021-04-10T18:41:31.796138 #52] FATAL -- : [b85580d2-cfac-4a60-b9e4-e46bbbc031c6]
Apr 10 01:41:31 PM  18:41:31 web.1    | [b85580d2-cfac-4a60-b9e4-e46bbbc031c6] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)):
```

#### error in rspec when calling `user.update(verification_pin_expires_at: DateTime.now + 2.hours)`

```
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
```

I also get the error if calling `save!` in the `User` model, like

```
  def set_verification_attributes
    self.verification_pin = 6.times.map { |i| i.zero? ? rand(1..9) : rand(10) }.join.to_i,
    self.verification_pin_expires_at = DateTime.now + 2.hours
    self.save!
  end
```

#### User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include WorkflowActiverecord

  workflow_column :status
  workflow do
    state :registered do
      event :verify, transition_to: :verified
      event :archive, transition_to: :deleted
    end
    state :verified do
      event :archive, transition_to: :deleted
    end
    state :deleted
  end

  scope :active, -> { where.not(status: 'deleted') }
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :zxcvbnable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :state, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::State', optional: true
  delegate :name, :slug, :abbr, to: :state, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  has_one :verification, dependent: :destroy_async
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :verification
  delegate :address_zip, :address_line_1, :address_city, to: :verification, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  has_many :issue_issuables, as: :issuable, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :issues, through: :issue_issuables
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :replies, through: :comments, class_name: 'Comment'
  has_many :upvotes, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :follows, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :support_requests, dependent: :destroy_async
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy_async

  has_many :state_moderators, foreign_key: :moderator_id, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :states, through: :state_moderators

  has_one :politician, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::Politician', dependent: :nullify
  delegate :title, :district, to: :politician, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  has_one :voter_record, through: :verification
  delegate :representatives, :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name, to: :voter_record, prefix: false, allow_nil: true
  alias current_representatives representatives

  has_one_attached :avatar
  validates :avatar, content_type: %r{\Aimage/.*\z}
```

#### user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'relationships' do
    it { is_expected.to have_one(:politician).optional }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:state).optional }
    it { is_expected.to have_one  :verification }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :comments }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :replies }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :upvotes }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :votes }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :follows }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :state_moderators }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :states }
    it { is_expected.to have_many :questions }
  end

  describe 'methods' do
    describe 'set_verification_attributes' do
      let(:user) { build(:user) }

      it 'sets the verification_pin field to be an 6 digit integer' do
        expect(user.verification_pin).to be(nil)
        user.set_verification_attributes
        expect(user.verification_pin).to be_a(Integer)
        expect(user.verification_pin.to_s.length).to eq(6)
      end

      it 'sets the verification_pin_expires_at to be approximately two hours from the current time' do
        expect(user.verification_pin_expires_at).to be(nil)
        user.set_verification_attributes
        expect(user.verification_pin_expires_at.change(sec: 0)).to eq((DateTime.now.in_time_zone('UTC') + 2.hours).change(sec: 0))
      end
    end

    describe 'verifiable' do
      let(:user) { build(:user) }

      it 'returns true if verification_pin_expires_at is not nil and the current time is less than or equal to verification_pin_expires_at' do
        user.verification_pin_expires_at = DateTime.now + 2.hours
        expect(user.verifiable?(user.verification_pin)).to eq(true)
      end

      it 'returns false if verification_pin_expires_at is nil' do
        expect(user.verification_pin_expires_at).to be(nil)
        expect(user.verifiable?(user.verification_pin)).to be(false)
      end

      it 'returns false if the current time is greater than the verification_pin_expires_at time' do
        user.verification_pin_expires_at = DateTime.now
        expect(user.verifiable?(user.verification_pin)).to eq(false)
      end

      it 'returns false if the current time is not expired but the pin does not match' do
        user.verification_pin_expires_at = DateTime.now + 2.hours
        expect(user.verifiable?(1)).to eq(false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### application_record.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'
end
```

#### render log

```
Apr 10 02:17:02 PM  19:17:02 web.1    | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Apr 10 02:17:02 PM  19:17:02 web.1    | Use Ctrl-C to stop
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | I, [2021-04-10T19:17:06.689547 #52]  INFO -- : source=rack-timeout id=00be6221-dd11-4497-b327-776272451a45 timeout=90000ms state=ready
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | I, [2021-04-10T19:17:06.690708 #52]  INFO -- : [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] Started GET "/graphql/playground" for 10.100.0.10 at 2021-04-10 19:17:06 +0000
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | D, [2021-04-10T19:17:06.690920 #52] DEBUG -- : source=rack-timeout id=00be6221-dd11-4497-b327-776272451a45 timeout=90000ms service=2ms state=active
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | F, [2021-04-10T19:17:06.701530 #52] FATAL -- : [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2]
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)):
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2]
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] redis (4.2.5) lib/redis.rb:836:in `set'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:397:in `block (2 levels) in write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:25:in `with'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:397:in `block in write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:478:in `failsafe'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:391:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:150:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:81:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:465:in `block in write'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:686:in `block in instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/hooks/active_support_notifications.rb:19:in `block in instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/hooks/active_support_notifications.rb:18:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:686:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:463:in `write'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] /opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb:87:in `method_missing'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/store_proxy/redis_cache_store_proxy.rb:32:in `write'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/store_proxy/redis_cache_store_proxy.rb:19:in `increment'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/cache.rb:74:in `do_count'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/cache.rb:27:in `count'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/throttle.rb:31:in `matched_by?'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:77:in `block in throttled?'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:76:in `any?'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:76:in `throttled?'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:109:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:32:in `call_with_appsignal_monitoring'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:17:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-contrib (2.3.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:19:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] meta_request (0.7.2) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:151:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:150:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:74:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:76:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-reverse-proxy (0.12.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/roundtrip.rb:19:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] rack-reverse-proxy (0.12.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/middleware.rb:25:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:248:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | [65738514-5973-443d-a3df-cf11d8d4d5c2] puma (5.2.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
Apr 10 02:17:06 PM  19:17:06 web.1    | I, [2021-04-10T19:17:06.702073 #52]  INFO -- : source=rack-timeout id=00be6221-dd11-4497-b327-776272451a45 timeout=90000ms service=13ms state=completed
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | I, [2021-04-10T19:17:11.690657 #52]  INFO -- : source=rack-timeout id=d393516a-0aa0-4a47-95d7-af9c937da8ab timeout=90000ms state=ready
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | D, [2021-04-10T19:17:11.690892 #52] DEBUG -- : source=rack-timeout id=d393516a-0aa0-4a47-95d7-af9c937da8ab timeout=90000ms service=0ms state=active
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | I, [2021-04-10T19:17:11.697669 #52]  INFO -- : [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] Started GET "/graphql/playground" for 10.100.0.10 at 2021-04-10 19:17:11 +0000
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | F, [2021-04-10T19:17:11.721655 #52] FATAL -- : [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067]
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)):
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067]
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] redis (4.2.5) lib/redis.rb:836:in `set'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:397:in `block (2 levels) in write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:25:in `with'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:397:in `block in write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:478:in `failsafe'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:391:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:150:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb:81:in `write_entry'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:465:in `block in write'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:686:in `block in instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/hooks/active_support_notifications.rb:19:in `block in instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/hooks/active_support_notifications.rb:18:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:686:in `instrument'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache.rb:463:in `write'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] /opt/render/project/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb:87:in `method_missing'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/store_proxy/redis_cache_store_proxy.rb:32:in `write'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/store_proxy/redis_cache_store_proxy.rb:19:in `increment'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/cache.rb:74:in `do_count'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/cache.rb:27:in `count'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/throttle.rb:31:in `matched_by?'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:77:in `block in throttled?'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:76:in `any?'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack/configuration.rb:76:in `throttled?'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-attack (6.5.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:109:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:32:in `call_with_appsignal_monitoring'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] appsignal (3.0.2) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:17:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-contrib (2.3.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:19:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] meta_request (0.7.2) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] railties (6.0.3.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:151:in `block in call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:150:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] activesupport (6.0.3.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
Apr 10 02:17:11 PM  19:17:11 web.1    | [08a4f5ce-7c8b-426d-87bf-fbe87be63067] actionpack (6.0.3.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
```

#### rspec

```
  1) User methods set_verification_attributes sets the verification_pin_expires_at to be approximately two hours from the current time
     Failure/Error: self.save!
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:154:in `set_verification_attributes'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:78:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you please show the full error, with all context? Clearly that line of code, in and of itself, isn't the problem - you're just calling a standard rails method with a named argument. Perhaps the error is in a `before_save` callback or similar, that you haven't actually shown us above?

Comment: I would bet good money that this error is caused by the [Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/). (And just to be clear, I assume you upgraded ruby from `2.x.x-->3.0.1`, not from `3.0.0-->3.0.1`?) I can probably show exactly how to fix the issue if you reveal the full error context; it's most likely resolved by introducing a double splat (`**`) operator into a method call, to explicitly convert positional arguments into keyword arguments.

Comment: @TomLord There are no callbacks on the model.

Comment: Correct @TomLord upgraded from 2.7.2

Comment: I don't believe you  What does the full stacktrace say? Any hints that something else is being invoked, **for example**, something tucked away in `WorkflowActiverecord` or `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: Or, maybe, there's a 3rd party gem involved that isn't compatible with ruby 3.0. (Again, the stacktrace should hopefully reveal this as the culprit!) -- In which case hopefully there's an updated version you could upgrade to.

Comment: I've added the application record above. Get same error if I remove WorkflowActiverecord from the model

Comment: Hmm -- That's hard to read because there's so much "noise" in the error log. What about that simpler scenario of just calling `user.save!`, e.g. in a spec or rails console?

Comment: I've added the spec log above. The actual method is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... It seems [this line in `ActiveSupport v6.0.3.6`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0073c7b29339b2ee1e11aa5c9622ea452d0633fc/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb#L397) is calling [this method in redis](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/7587668c1fe5c1f30387d80b5682a93678be40aa/lib/redis.rb#L836) with 3 arguments instead of 2; exactly like the error says!

And just as I suspected, [that's already been fixed in the master branch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/466a54f766bc3acaeb8f90a08a764c20e6b7c023/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb#L406). [Here was the commit that introduced the fix](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/37c19f7ebcf542af968a4983b3296b9fa283a0dc).

So in other words, I reckon you've found a bug in rails 6.0 working with ruby 3.0.

Additionally, it seems that this bug has already been [backported into the `6.0-stable` branch](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39844) and, according to the comments, "will be included in Rails `6.0.4`".

---

tl;dr: Either downgrade ruby back to `2.7`, or upgrade rails to `6.1`, or add to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "6-0-stable"
```

Comment: That fixed the build error but not the error with rspec

Comment: Run the spec with —backtrace to see more context